# Orders do not appear in "Orders" tab in customer's account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I'm facing an issue where the "/account/orders" page doesn't show the customers' orders history.

- In the "/view-order/xxxxxx" endpoint we can see the order without having any problems.
- In WooCommerce admin all orders show up correctly but the thing is that I can't get them to appear in the front end for each customer.

I thought that it was a custom function's issue that I've created but I have integrated the same script on another website and the orders appear like normal.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'woo_checkout_custom_meta' );
function woo_checkout_custom_meta( $order_id ){
  if( !cart_has_X_product() ){ return; }

  if( !empty( $_POST['{field_name}'] ) ){
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '{field_name}', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['{field_name}'] ) );
  }

 // Some other "Update_post_meta" functions
}
```

The "myaccount/orders" page hasn't been changed, we use the default one. So I don't know what's wrong with this.

WP ver.: **5.6.1**

WooCommerce ver.: **4.9.2**

**P.S.:** I've disabled several plugins that I thought might have caused the issue and nothing happened.

**P.S. #2:** I've also cleared the cache. Still nothing.

**P.S. #3:** Downgraded WooCommerce to ver. 4.9.1. Still...

There was an issue online regarding the Yoast SEO plugin. I don't use that one. so...

Any ideas on that?

Comment: In **WooCommerce** > **Settings** > **Advanced** have you checked the *Orders* field in the *Account endpoints* section? What value is entered?

Comment: @Vdgaetano 
Sure, it's set up like this:
**Orders -> orders** /
**View order -> view-order**
etc.
etc.
etc.

Comment: What is shown on the `www.yourdomain.com/my-account/orders` page? (replace *my-account* with the account page slug) Could you post a screenshot? Could the order table have been hidden with a CSS rule? Have you checked your log file for errors?

Comment: @Vdgaetano I can see only two orders that were made about a month ago. But there were more orders before and after that date. 
I've also checked that CSS thing you mentioned and everything are set correctly. 
Error logs don't show any errors related to that. Maybe a function causes a "return" that prevents that from completing orders parsing from DB?